# Where to locate CORE_VM_ENDPOINT core.yaml file when setting up fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am following [instructions](https://openblockchain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Network-setup/#Determine%20value%20for%20CORE_VM_ENDPOINT%20variable) on Fabric Network Setup. Using Vagrant. Need to cetermine value for `CORE_VM_ENDPOINT` variable in `core.yaml`.

There is two `core.yaml` files in my `~/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric` located in examples folder and sampleconfig folder. However none of these mentions `CORE_VM_ENDPOINT`

So, what would be the appropriate file to edit, or I am missing any steps?

Answer (score 0):

core.yaml file is a file that you can refer to find information regarding environment variables the fabric-peers use. Eg: If you see the following:

```
vm:
   endpoint:
```

in core.yaml file then it's corresponding environment variable will be CORE_VM_ENDPOINT. This environment variable is specified in another file (usually named docker-compose.yaml).

So you need to specify CORE_VM_ENDPOINT in a new yaml file that you will use with docker-compose to start containers.

[Here is a sample yaml file](https://github.com/sharma66mahesh/fabric-network/blob/master/base/peer-base.yaml)

[Here is another one](https://github.com/sharma66mahesh/fabric-network/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml)

Comment: Thank you, do you know of any fabric v1.4 network setup repositories that would be easy to configure to pbft consensus with corresponding orgs and peers (in vagrant dev env)?